# How to undelete files on ext4 filesystem without unmounting or mounting read-only

Tags: ext4

I accidentally deleted a user account, including the home directory (with userdel -r), and now I need to recover the contents of the home directory.
Is there a way to do this without umounting the filesystem or remounting the filesystem read-only?

Thanks

Comment: to `grep` a mounted root filesystem, see [How can I recover/undelete files from an ext4 partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/170857/how-can-i-recover-undelete-files-from-an-ext4-partition/1223631#1223631)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bet on that, but I believe there's no way to undelete files on a mounted read-write partition.

The main reason being that the longer you keep a filesystem up on a machine, the more likely the deallocated data will be overwritten by new stuff from apps and other users.

So instead of loosing time (and data!) trying to figure out a way, just immediately do a `mount -o 'remount,ro' /home`, and if you have a lot of users that will get angry at you because of that, then you `dd if=/dev/sdXX of=home_partition_backup.img` and once it's done, you `mount -o 'remount,rw' /home`.

Then you can do whatever undelete procedure you want on the image you've copied from the partition.

Comment: what utility do you recommend I use for undeleting files and folders from the image?